# left border of a menu doesn't show

Tags: nav

I have a simple nav and I want remove all left borders but not the one of the first child one, with css I did this:

```
ul.nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px;
}

ul.nav li {
    float:left;
}

ul.nav li a{ 
    display: block;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CCC), to(#999));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left:none;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

but it won't show the first child left border

Comment: didn't understand your question well enough? do u need a left border or do u want to remove it all?

Comment: i want to remove all left borders but not the border of the first element in the list

Comment: now do you have borders? or where do u have borders?

Comment: with that code, i have border in the top and in the right, but not in the left and i want the first item in the list to have the left border, but not the others list items

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change

```
    ul.nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px;
    }
```

to

```
    ul.nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
```